# Openx Ad Delivery Issues

Tags: php, banner, ads, openx

**My System**

- Apache 2.2.9
- PHP 5.2.9
- MySQL client version: 5.1.28-rc
- Openx v2.8.5

I am using the Javascript single page call to serve my ads. I am running an in house CMS where everything is processed through a template.php file.

**My Issue**
The success of an ad being served seems to be very hit and miss. The placement or type of the ad does not seem to matter. For some reason, the loading of the ads is very spotty. Each page serves an average of 3 ads. Sometimes none show up, sometimes 2, sometimes 1. There does not seem to be any consistency in the problem occurring. The problem seems to have worsened since I updated to the most recent version and started using Single Page Call.

I have checked the source. All Javascript script is in place, but the ad content is not generated under the script where it should be. The space where the ad should be is just empty.

No Javascript errors are generated.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For me, this happened when the campaigns assigned to the zone were all contract and there was no Remnants assigned. OpenX basically had no banners with impressions left to display.

Also, another time t his happened was with their implementation of Single Page Call. OpenX pre-loads all zones you have put into the array on every page, regardless of if they are displayed or not. So if you have a lot of zones, the ones near the end of the array can not get any ads because the ones above it take all the ads with impressions.

If you have a CMS with a lot of advertising zones, you're going to have to dynamically control the Javascript array to only load the zones needed for display on that specific page. I have a solution for Joomla if you need more details.

Comment: After much heartache, I found the problem to be empty banners still attached to the zone. I don't really know how this happened. I would think that when a banner, campaign, or advertiser is deleted that it's attachment to the zone should be deleted as well. However, it just looked like through the years there must have been some hiccups in the process and failed to delete the relationship. This caused Openx to load empty banners into the page.